# Hot get I18.locale from a .js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I am trying to do an 'if' statement depending on the language and do to find the right way to make JS to find the locale.

As as I trial I have tried with similar combinations to this, but no avail.

```
alert(<%= I18n.locale.to_s %>);
```

The page loads but no alert is shown.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the quotes.

```
alert('<%= I18n.locale.to_s %>');
```